# Screen on Max Brightness Appears Slightly Dim After Sleeping, MacBook Pro 2015

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, display, catalina, sleep-wake

**The issue:**
The screen appears about 2-3 dots dimmer on max brightness after waking from sleep for more than 30 minutes. I only noticed this a few months after upgrading to Catalina, it's been ongoing ever since.

**My settings:**
No auto-adjusted brightness, disabled screen temperature modifiers like NightShift/Flux, slightly higher gamma color profile for better contrast/brightness (it looks a bit faded otherwise).

**My computer:**
MacBook Pro 13" early 2015 mid-tier model with Catalina 10.15.4. (bought in 2017 used, no repairs or hardware issues the whole year. Great battery cycle life).

**My Temporary solution:**
Resetting the PRAM (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). This fix lasts until I close my laptop and let it sleep overnight usually. Sometimes I've had success reducing the brightness before putting it to sleep. I am not completely sure if this is hardware or software-related.

There have been rare/infrequent occasions when my display would do weird things after waking from sleep. There was one incident of my display completely blanking out with a white pixelated screen for a moment (like an old static TV out of tune). A few other incidents where the display blinks black or totally freezes. It was at first a problem with video playback and hardware acceleration, but now I am beginning to believe it may be a hardware-related problem (though this Mac doesn't have a graphics card).

Answer (score 6):

Just figured this out for my case. I had already disabled the brightness from automatically adjusting. Every time my computer woke up from sleep however the brightness would still drop to around 50%.

Turns out I also needed uncheck the box to "Slightly dim the display while on battery power"

System Preferences > Battery > Slightly dim the display while on battery power

See the image below:

[image: uncheck auto dim on battery]

Comment: [Good find on these close questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/366958/5472) - thanks for the clear answer.

Comment: Already disabled for me when not plugged in and still dimming. Also turned off the Automatic setting in display.

Comment: Still not fixed for me. After closing and opening the lid, the brightness goes down. All automatic settings are off.

Answer (score 0):

The above "Slightly dim the display while on battery power" was already disabled on my MBP, and still had the same issues.

The problem for me was in Battery > Low Power Mode was set to "Always".

Switched to "Only on battery" (or "Never") and no more dimming on wake up.

[image: switching low power mode settings from always to only on battery]