# How can I turn off auto-dimming of the screen with `defaults write`?

Tags: macos, screen, defaults

Apple has a default setting that I find troublesome, where it automatically adjusts the brightness of the screen according to what it guesses is best for me, even when I'm constantly fighting with it to change the brightness.

The fix for this problem is here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/366962/3553

But how can I do this in a script, with `defaults write`?

Comment: Not sure if you can do a script using defaults write, but maybe you can tinker with `pmset` in terminal instead, as there's many commands using `pmset`. I know there is a PowerManagement.plist you can read `defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.PowerManagement.plist` but I don't think the setting you are after is located there. But `pmset` is probably better than defaults writes. Also, this is a little bit outdated but this link might explain a few things about power management/pmset: https://eclecticlight.co/2017/01/20/power-management-in-detail-using-pmset/

Comment: On further investigation, you could read additional Power Management plists by entering `defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.PowerManagement.UUID.plist` where the `UUID` is unique to your Mac, which you can find in System Profiler. Hope that helps